# LEFT OUTER JOIN with mySQL analyse all rows

Tags: mysql

my tables are simple:

```
mysql> desc muralentry ;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_src_id     | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| content         | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc muralentry_user ;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| muralentry_id   | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userinfo_id     | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Im doing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM muralentry
LEFT OUTER JOIN muralentry_user ON (muralentry.id = muralentry_user.muralentry_id)
WHERE user_src_id = 1
```

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys                                         | key                                 | key_len | ref                                      | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | muralentry                 | ref  | muralentry_99bd10ae                                   | muralentry_99bd10ae                 | 4       | const                                    |  686 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | muralentry_user            | ref  | muralentry_id,muralentry_user_bcd7114e                | muralentry_user_bcd7114e            | 4       | muralentry.id                            |   15 |                 |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------+
```

Good result (for me :D)
But, when i add another where clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM muralentry
LEFT OUTER JOIN muralentry_user ON (muralentry.id = muralentry_user.muralentry_id)
WHERE user_src_id = 1 OR userinfo_id = 1;
```

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys                                         | key                                 | key_len | ref                                      | rows    | Extra           |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | muralentry                 | ALL  | muralentry_99bd10ae                                   | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL                                     | 1140932 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | muralentry_user            | ref  | muralentry_id,muralentry_user_bcd7114e                | muralentry_user_bcd7114e            | 4       | muralentry.id                            |      15 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
```

Wow... the result if ALOT worst...
How can i "fix" this?
Should i create some index to do this job? Or recreate my query?

I'm expecting the following result: 'muralentry' rows where the user is 'user_src_id' AND the 'muralentry_user' rows where he is 'userinfo_id'.

-- edit --

I edited the question because when I wrote an AND actually wanted an OR... sorry for that!

Comment: What's the actual performance on these queries?  Could be that MySQL decided there are too few rows to bother using an index in the second query.

Comment: mysql client says - 1: 0.0 sec 2: 12.60 sec

Comment: And do you have an index on the `userinfo_id` column?  If not, I would suggest adding one and see what difference it makes.

Comment: still the same, mysql wont use the key...

Comment: What does the plan/execution time look like for this:  SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM muralentry
JOIN muralentry_user ON (muralentry.id = muralentry_user.muralentry_id)
WHERE userinfo_id = 1;

Comment: the result is near identical to the query with the 'OR' : 10.34 sec. The explain got a similar results too.